# time_() = time.time() SyntaxError: “can't assign to function call” PYTHON

Tags: python

input

```
time_() = time.time()
```

output

```
time_() = time.time()
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

howto fix this?

Comment: you are supposed to do `time_=time.time()`

Comment: What do you intend this code to do in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says you are trying to assign to a function call. If you want to assign function to a variable time_ you should do it like this

```
time_ = time.time()
```